# Select all records where the day of month is between 30 and 15

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table called **Liabilities** which has the following columns **loan_name, institution_name, starting_date, emi, closing_date**. The type of `starting_date` and `closing_date` is varchar.

I am trying to write a query which gets data (EMI reminder) where the day of `starting_date` is between 30 and 15.

Example:- I have written the following query, it works in scenarios like if today's date is **07-11-2014**. Below query will return data for **next 15 day**s but if the date is **30-11-2014** then it **won't return** results for **next 15 days**. Kindly check below query.

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    owner_name as client_name,
    loan_name as scheme_name,
    institution_name as institution_name,
    starting_date as date_of_deduction,
    emi as amount,
    closing_date,
    "Liabilities" as instrument
FROM (`liability`)
WHERE `user_id` = '46'
AND
    (STR_TO_DATE(starting_date, "%d") between STR_TO_DATE("30-11-2014", "%d")
    and STR_TO_DATE("15-12-2014", "%d"))
AND
    (STR_TO_DATE(closing_date, "%d-%m-%Y") >= STR_TO_DATE("30-11-2014", "%d-%m-%Y"))
```

I want records between 30th - 15th of every month as I want to send emails to clients. I have 3 records for reference

```
1) starting date :- 17-09-2012 
2) starting date :- 06-10-2010 
3) starting date :- 21-08-2014
```

I want the query to **return record 2 which is 06-10-2010** since the day of month is between 30th and 15th.

Comment: What is your date column type = varchar? datetime?

Comment: both starting_date and closing_date are varchar

Comment: well, I strongly recommend to use datetime() type if possible, it will be much easier to query database against datetime type

Comment: I wanted to save date in dd-mm-yyyy format, thats why I decided to use varchar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `starting_date` field is a varchar and you store the date in `dd-mm-yyyy` format, you need to convert `starting_date` to datetime using [STR_TO_DATE() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) like below

```
STR_TO_DATE(starting_date, "%d-%m-%Y")
```

then check if the day of the above value is 30 or above, or 15 or below using [DAYOFMONTH() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofmonth)

```
DAYOFMONTH(STR_TO_DATE(starting_date, "%d-%m-%Y")) >= 30 
    OR DAYOFMONTH(STR_TO_DATE(starting_date, "%d-%m-%Y")) <= 15
```

The following query should return the correct records

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    owner_name as client_name,
    loan_name as scheme_name,
    institution_name as institution_name,
    starting_date as date_of_deduction,
    emi as amount,
    closing_date,
    "Liabilities" as instrument
FROM (`liability`)
WHERE `user_id` = '46'
AND
    (DAYOFMONTH(STR_TO_DATE(starting_date, "%d-%m-%Y")) >= 30 
    OR DAYOFMONTH(STR_TO_DATE(starting_date, "%d-%m-%Y")) <= 15)
```

Comment: I Want records between 30th - 15th of every month. I have 3 records
1) starting date :- 17-09-2012
2) starting date :- 06-10-2010
3) starting date :- 21-08-2014
I want the query to return record 2 which is 06-10-2010 as it is between 30th and 15th...

Comment: Please check the updated answer, I think it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    owner_name        as client_name,
    loan_name         as scheme_name,
    institution_name  as institution_name,
    starting_date     as date_of_deduction,
    emi as amount,
    closing_date,
    "Liabilities" as instrument
FROM
    (liability)
WHERE
    user_id = '46'
AND TO_DAYS(STR_TO_DATE(starting_date, "%d-%m-%Y")) >  TO_DAYS(STR_TO_DATE("30-11-2014", "%d-%m-%Y"))
AND TO_DAYS(STR_TO_DATE(starting_date, "%d-%m-%Y")) <  TO_DAYS(STR_TO_DATE("15-12-2014", "%d-%m-%Y"))
AND TO_DAYS(STR_TO_DATE(closing_date,  "%d-%m-%Y")) >= TO_DAYS(STR_TO_DATE("30-11-2014", "%d-%m-%Y"))
```

Comment: No its still returning zero rows... Basically it is a monthly reminder... Result should give me all the records whose starting date is between 30th to 15th. I have few records whose starting date is 06, 10 and 12